# How to print only if X amount of time has elapsed

Tags: python, itunes, elapsedtime

I currently have a script that parses information from iTunes about the current song playing and prints it. It only prints if the song has changed. Now I would like to make it print only if one minute of the song has elapsed but cannot figure out how to do this.

This is the code I currently have:

```
def giveData():
    last_title, last_artist, last_album = None, None, None
    while True:
       template = '"%s" by %s (%d)\n from %s'
       info = ''

iTunesCount = app('System Events').processes[its.name == 'iTunes'].count()
if iTunesCount > 0:
  iTunes = app('iTunes')
  if iTunes.player_state.get() == k.playing:
    track = iTunes.current_track.get()
    artist = track.artist.get()
    title = track.name.get()
    album = track.album.get()
    stars = track.rating.get()/20

     if title != last_title or artist != last_artist or album != last_album:

      last_title, last_artist, last_album = title, artist, album
      info = template % (title, artist, stars, album)

    # Trying new solution, still printing songs that haven't been playing
    # for 60s, just delaying printing them by 60s:

      now = time.time()
      future = now + 60
      while time.time() < future:
        pass

      song_info = title + " - " + artist
      print song_info`
```

Comment: Whats the python library that you are using ?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.8

Comment: We'd need to know how you are accessing the iTunes information.

Comment: I am using appscript, I will update my original post. Sorry, this is my first post, thanks for the patience!

Comment: Where do you initialize `last_title`, `last_artist`, & `last_album`? Where do you call `giveData()`? Fix your indenting...

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a time counter?

```
import time

now = time.time()
future = now + 60
while time.time() < future:
    pass

print '60 seconds have passed'
```

or as @Undeterminant pointed out just use

```
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I updated it now, previous code prolly wouldn't have worked ;)

Comment: I am not getting a print this way. Maybe I am not putting the statement in the right place, right now it is right where the comment is on my original post.

Comment: I am actually having some issues again. It is printing songs that have not elapsed for 60s, it is just delaying printing them by 60s. Maybe I did not write it correctly. I will update my original post.

Comment: You just implemented a really inefficient `time.sleep(1)`.

Comment: yes, seems so, @NikolaDraca you could give 

`import time

time.sleep(60)

print '60 seconds have passed'`

.. if the script is fired every time a song starts, then the code should work. Is that the behaviour? Where do you use giveData() ?